# Code throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when writing to file

Tags: java, android, apache-httpcomponents

Hi I am using the following code to handle fileuploads at the server side on android.I have tested this with a jsp and it works as expected but on the android it throws the  exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Arguments out of bounds on this line .
Just found out that files less than 100 kb are being uploaded successfully.Any idea what the reason could be .It is also throwing an out of memory exception randomly when the file is big.

```
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
```

Could someone suggest a work around for this please.Thanks

Relevant code:

```
        String contentType;
        byte[] dataBytes =null ;
        try {
            dataBytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        contentType=String.valueOf(request.getFirstHeader("Content-Type"));
        DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataBytes));
        int formDataLength=dataBytes.length;
        int byteRead = 0;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength)
        {
            try {
                byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,
                        formDataLength);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            totalBytesRead += byteRead;
        }
        String file = new String(dataBytes);
        String saveFile =file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
        saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
        saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,
                saveFile.indexOf("\""));
        int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
        String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,
                contentType.length());
        int pos=0;
        pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;

        int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
        int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
        int endPos = ((file.substring(0,boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new
                FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+saveFile);

        fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));//exception thrown here
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
        try{
            jo.put("name", saveFile);
            jo.put("size", formDataLength);
            jo.put("url","ok"); 
            jo.put("thumbnail_url","");
            jo.put("delete_url", "");
            jo.put("delete_type","DELETE");
            ja.put(jo);
        }
        catch(JSONException je){
            je.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringEntity se=new StringEntity(ja.toString());
        response.setEntity(se);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

Logcat index.out of bounds exception output:

```
10-07 21:39:11.197: E/AndroidRuntime(897): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-13 exiting due to uncaught exception
10-07 21:39:11.207: E/AndroidRuntime(897): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Arguments out of bounds
10-07 21:39:11.207: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:288)
10-07 21:39:11.207: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.xlnc.webapp.FileListHandler.handle(FileListHandler.java:168)
10-07 21:39:11.207: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.doService(HttpService.java:243)
10-07 21:39:11.207: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:187)
10-07 21:39:11.207: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.xlnc.webapp.WebServer$WorkerThread.run(WebServer.java:140)
```

Logcat out of memory:

```
 10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-28 exiting due to uncaught exception
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.nio.CharArrayBuffer.<init>(CharArrayBuffer.java:43)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.nio.ReadWriteCharArrayBuffer.<init>(ReadWriteCharArrayBuffer.java:47)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.nio.BufferFactory.newCharBuffer(BufferFactory.java:84)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:57)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.allocateMore(CharsetDecoder.java:293)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:250)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(Charset.java:768)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:238)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:193)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.xlnc.webapp.FileListHandler.handle(FileListHandler.java:141)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.doService(HttpService.java:243)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:187)
10-07 21:35:36.587: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.xlnc.webapp.WebServer$WorkerThread.run(WebServer.java:140)
```

Comment: Getting the indexof and using it on substring looks like a loaded weapon. Are you sure it isn't the cause?

Comment: please paste the logcat output.

Comment: Your while loop is broken. What happens if there is an exception there? Put some prints for the IndexOutOfBounds problem it should be obvious that you are referring out side of dataBytes.

Comment: @kalz,  Two things, why are you not using a `Reader/Writer` class?  If the format is text then there is no reason to use a `Stream` class.  Secondly, paste an example of the text you are trying to parse.  I tried to look at your code but I'm unsure about the entire pos = indexof(filename\n) and all that,  there is most likely and easier way to do what your attempting.

Comment: @mrres1 thanks for getting back I am trying to parse a file upload request on android and save the file to sdcard.I have rewritten the code using commonsfileupload and the issue is solved.But I would need some help uploading big files.Will post a new question on that.